# WPF binding IValueConverter and the width of another control

Tags: wpf, binding, width, ivalueconverter

---

The following code worked fine. There was an error elsewhere in the code. Still, the advice given is good.

---

I am trying to bind the `Width` of a `TextBox` to a percentage of the `Width` of a parent control. I know I can accomplish something similar by simply setting a `Margin`, but I was wondering why this doesn't work.

First, I set a reference to an `IValueConverter` in the resources collection of my user control:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <local:TextBoxWidthConverter x:Key="txtWidthConv" />
</UserControl.Resources>
```

In the main xaml, I have the following:

```
<StackPanel Name="parentPanel" Width="300">
  <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"    
       VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" Name="scroller" Width="{Binding Width,    
       ElementName=parentPanel, Converter={StaticResource txtWidthConv}}">           
     <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
       <TextBox></TextBox>
     </StackPanel>
   </ScrollViewer>
</StackPanel>
```

The ivalueconverter looks like this:

```
public class TextBoxWidthConverter : IValueConverter
{

    #region IValueConverter Members

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        double result = (double)value;

        if (!Double.IsNaN(result))
        {
            result = result * .25;
        }
        else
        {
            result = 100D;
        }

        return result;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new System.NotImplementedException("Not implemented.");
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Setting the width property does nothing here, let alone setting the `IValueConverter`.  I would expect the `ScrollViewer` to be 1/4 the width of the parent `StackPanel`.

Comment: I tried your XAML with a statically set `Width`, and it worked fine.

Comment: Same here, tried it in VS2008 and the `ScrollViewer` is 1/4 of the size of `ParentPanel` - if you remove the `StackPanel` around the `TextBox`, the `TextBox` will expand to the size of the `ScrollViewer`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the ScrollViewer's `HorizontalAlignment` to something other than `Stretch`.

Also, you should bind to the [`ActualWidth` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.actualwidth.aspx).

Comment: That seems to make no difference.

Comment: @Bob: Did you try `ActualWidth`?

Comment: Yes: Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=parentPanel, Converter={StaticResource txtWidthConv}}"

Comment: If you set `Width` to `75` manually, does it work?  It does for me.

Comment: What I'm trying to do is have the width bind to the width of the parentPanel and automatically make it .25 * that width.

Comment: @Bob: I realize that.  Is the problem in the layout or in the BindingConverter?

Comment: I don't know. I set a breakpoint in the converter, but it's never hit.

Comment: There's something wrong with my project. My client insists on VS2008 and .NET 3.5, but the code works fine VS2010 targeted to .NET 4. I know that can't be the problem, though. This stuff isn't that recent. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Let the layout system work for you instead of fighting it. Grid will automatically handle relative sizing:

```
<StackPanel Name="parentPanel" Width="300">
  <Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition />
      <ColumnDefinition Width="3*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"    
       VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" Name="scroller">           
      <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <TextBox></TextBox>
      </StackPanel>
    </ScrollViewer>
  </Grid>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: I know how to solve the layout issue. I want to know why the binding doesn't work. I'll do some more tests. I think something must be funky with my project.

Comment: Huh, the code works as expected in VS2010 with .NET 4, but not in VS2008 with .NET 3.5.